# Незапланированный выход из цикла

Tags: php, база-данных, cms, циклы, while

Вывожу в цикле значение из базы для фида, предварительно вычисляя цену (там есть еще значения, но они для вопроса не важны).

Сам запрос к базе:

```
$simpla->db->query("SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1");
$simpla->db->query("SELECT v.price, v.id as variant_id, p.name as product_name, v.name as variant_name, v.position as variant_position, p.id as product_id, p.url, p.annotation, 
                    pc.category_id, c.url as c_url, c.name as c_name, c.percent1, c.percent2, c2.name as brand_name, i.filename as image, v.st_barcode as gtin, v.sale_price as sale_price, p.in_stock, p.sale              

                    FROM __variants v LEFT JOIN __products p ON v.product_id=p.id
                    LEFT JOIN __products_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id AND pc.position=(SELECT MIN(position) FROM __products_categories WHERE product_id=p.id LIMIT 1)
                    LEFT JOIN __categories c ON pc.category_id = c.id AND c.use_category_persent > 0
                    LEFT JOIN __categories c2 ON c.parent_id = c2.id
                    LEFT JOIN __images i ON p.id = i.product_id AND i.position=(SELECT MIN(position) FROM __images WHERE product_id=p.id LIMIT 1)
                    WHERE pc.category_id > 0 AND c.visible = 1 AND p.visible = 1 AND v.price > 0 AND (v.stock >0 OR v.stock is NULL) GROUP BY v.id ORDER BY p.id, v.position ");
```

Вычисления и вывод цен:

```
<?php while($p = $simpla->db->result()) {
    $price = $simpla->stalker->nuRound($simpla->money->markup($p->variant_id)); ?>
    <g:price><?=$price.' RUB'?></g:price>
<?php } ?>
```

При использовании функции markup почему-то происходит выход из цикла while. Сама функция markup:

```
public function markup($variant_id, $price=NULL)
{
    // Расчет стоимости с наценкой брендов
    // @peram - ИД варианта s_variants.id
    // @peram - Иная цена, при отсутствии берется цена варианта
    // @return - Итоговая цена варианта

    $this->db->query("SELECT c.percent1, c.percent2, v.price FROM __categories c
                      LEFT JOIN __products_categories pc ON c.id=pc.category_id
                      LEFT JOIN __variants v ON pc.product_id=v.product_id
                      WHERE v.id=? ORDER BY pc.position ASC LIMIT 1",
                      (int)$variant_id);

    $result = $this->db->result();

    if(!empty($result))
    {
        if (empty($price)) $price = $result->price;
        $markup = $result->percent1;
        $markdown = $result->percent2;

        if($markup > 0)
        {
            $price *= 1 + $markup / 100;
        }

        if($markdown > 0)
        {
            $price *= 1 - $markdown / 100;
        }

        return round($price, 2);
    }

    return 0;
}
}
```

Проблема: не могу понять почему цикл while конфликтует с функцией markup. Может вы сможете подсказать чего путного :) CMS, в которой идет работа SIMPLA.

Comment: Видимо класс работы с базой у этого магазина кривой (за $400 :) ). Сделали первый запрос и забирайте все полученные данные в массив (там метод results() кажется для этого есть), а потом уже по массиву делайте цикл.

Comment: Ваш код насилует базу. Если первый запрос вернёт 20-30 результатов то вы сделаете ещё 20-30 запросов к бд. Это крайне не оптимально. Лучше получить все нужные цены стразу одним отдельным запросом, запихнуть в хеш и доставать цену из него.

Comment: Всем спасибо) Помогло!